# Does Linq Exist for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linq

Just wanted to know if I can use Linq on Javascript arrays. If not is their a 3rd party tool I can use?

Comment: See http://jsinq.codeplex.com/ and http://www.codeplex.com/JSLINQ and http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jLINQ and http://netindonesia.net/blogs/jimmy/archive/2007/07/16/Javascript-LINQ_3F003F003F00_.aspx None are truly **Language Integrated**, and so miss the boat IMO. They offer nothing JavaScript 1.6 Array extensions don't do natively: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6

Comment: @Crescent Fresh, nice links: I guess on the flip side the advantage of the framework LINQ solns (instead of language integrated) is that they are compatible with more client javascript versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, however frameworks (eg jquery) has some functions that can be used.

It's funny this morning I wanted a String.ForEachEndsWith(arr[]) method.
So I created something like this:

```
 String.prototype.endsWith = function(str)
 { return (this.match(str + "$") == str) }

 String.prototype.forEachEndsWith = function(str_array)
 {
    var result = false;
    for(var index = 0;index < str_array.length;index++)
    {
        var current = str_array[index].toUpperCase();
        if (this.toUpperCase().endsWith(current))
        {
            result = true;
            return result;
        }
    }
    result = false;
    return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Linq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) is part of the .NET framework. It's not available in Javascript.

There are however similar solutions in various Javascript frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/vktawbzg/

**NPM:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqscript

**GITHUB:** https://github.com/sevensc/linqscript

take a look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqscript.

syntax e.g:

```
var fruits = new List<Fruits>();
var apple = new Fruit();
apple.Color = Color.Green;
apple.Name = "Apple";
fruits.Add(apple);

var redApple = new Fruit();
redApple.Color = Color.Red;
redApple.Name = "Apple";
fruits.Add(redApple);

var kiwi = new Fruit();
kiwi.Color = Color.Green;
kiwi.Name = "Kiwi";
fruits.Add(kiwi);

fruits.Where(x => x.Color === Color.Green);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's awesome. Available on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqjs

Please also consider my own library: Data-Forge is inspired by LINQ with a sprinkling of features from Pandas. It's great for working with data.

http://www.data-forge-js.com/

Available on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-forge